# PYTHONPATH vs symbolic link

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pycharm, pythonpath

Yesterday, I edited the `bin/activate` script of my virtualenv so that it sets the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include a development version of some external package. I had to do this because the `setup.py` of the package uses `distutils` and does not support the `develop` command à la `setuptools`. Setting `PYTHONPATH` works fine as far as using the Python interpreter in the terminal is concerned.

However, just now I opened the project settings in PyCharm and discovered that PyCharm is unaware of the external package in question - PyCharm lists neither the external package nor its path. Naturally, that's because PyCharm does not (and cannot reliably) parse or source the `bin/activate` script. I could manually add the path in the PyCharm project settings, but that means I have to repeat myself (once in `bin/activate`, and again in the PyCharm project settings). That's not DRY and that's bad.

Creating, in `site-packages`, a symlink that points to the external package is *almost* perfect. This way, at least the source editor of PyCharm can find the package and so does the Python interpreter in the terminal. However, somehow PyCharm still does not list the package in the project settings and I'm not sure if it's ok to leave it like that.

So how can I add the external package to my virtualenv/project in such a way that…

1. I don't have to repeat myself; and…
2. both the Python interpreter and PyCharm would be aware of it?

Comment: I think you should probably ask this question from the PyCharm developers, instead of SO, they'll have a better understanding regarding how and where PyCharm looks for packages / modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when a package is not using `setuptools` `pip` monkeypatches `setup.py` to force it to use `setuptools`.

Maybe you can remove that `PYTHONPATH` hack and `pip install -e /path/to/package`.

Comment: I forget which project this is for already, so I don't know which package is still using `distutils` in its `setup.py`, and I can't verify if this works. But this solution looks sensible and should work in theory, with reasonably recent versions of pip and setuptools. So I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to add path dynamically:

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    sys.path.insert(0. "/path/to/your/package/directory")
    import foo
```

But it is not the best solution because it is very likely that that code will not get into the final version of the application. One more option (and more appropriate imho) is to make simple setup.py file for package and deploy it in virtualenv with develop parameter or by pip with -e parameter:

```
python setup.py develop
```

or:

```
pip install -e /path/to/your/package/directory
```

http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#development-mode

Comment: Almost. There are ways to ensure the path is correct no matter where it happens to live.

Comment: It depends on where the file is located. That is basically never a good thing, though it's passable in one-off scripts that don't ever need to be migrated to another machine.

Comment: I've followed relative path techniques assuming an unchanging directory structure for the repo more or less doing stuff like `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))`
This operation is confined to `__main__`. Pretty ugly but it makes the repo immediately runnable no matter where its cloned on disk. This is more for the monorepo context to avoid catering the python environment per clone. The only requirement for the python environment is that all third party packages be installed in the site-packages or whatever makes sense. ....(continued)...

Comment: ...the other constraint is that all the python modules conduct their imports assuming some common parent root folder within the repo where all dependent modules can successfully import down from. All the child modules may have growing import paths showing up like `import projRoot.packageA.packageB.moduleX as moduleX`

Answer (score -1):

This is an improvement on ndpu's answer that will work regardless of where the real file is.

You can dereference the symlink and then set `sys.path` before importing local imports.

```
import os.path
import sys

# Ensure this file is dereferenced if it is a symlink
if __name__ == '__main__' and os.path.islink(__file__):
    try:
        sys.path.remove(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

# local imports go here
```

Comment: The `__file__` variable contains the path to the file that Python is currently importing! You are trying to add current module dir to sys.path? what is the point?

Comment: `__file__` will normally point to the location where the *symlink* lives, rather than the real location of the file, so this ensures the real file's directory is in the path. Calling `os.path.realpath` will ensure that the symlink is dereferenced.